# How to use <> operator in ScheduledAction Class (Visual Studio, Windows Phone 7.1)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Hi I need to use the  "<>" (not equal to) operator for a peice of coding which uses the SheduledAction class, but I keep getting this error:

```
Error   1   Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction' and 'Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction'
```

Here is my coding thats bringing up the error:

```
Dim hw As ScheduledAction = ScheduledActionService.Find("Hello World")

        If hw <> Nothing Then
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScheduledAction` type doesn't implement the equality operators so you need to do explicit reference equality via `Is` and `IsNot`

```
if hw IsNot Nothing Then
  ...
```